# I have a React component using Antd, need to style the background of every other row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have a component using Antd and I'm trying to use the `nth-child()` selector to style the background color of every other row but I don't know how to do it with Antd.

I read through their [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) and tried to apply that logic by adding `${Row}:nth-child(2){ background-color: white;}` by extending the styles of my Collapse component, but I get a type error saying that typeOf Row is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'

I have a code sandbox below with the initial styling and layout.

[image: Edit Q-56840430-BackgroundPanel]

Comment: Please add the relevant code here so that it can be solved without relying solely on a third party website

Comment: like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/q-56840430-backgroundpanel-zvj75. Just apply the style on a row

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your Body component like below using ant design class names:

```
const Body = styled.div`
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    .ant-row:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
`;
```